# React - Next Js not setting cookies after log in

Tags: node.js, reactjs, kubernetes, next.js, session-cookies

I have the following setup (domains are resolved locally):

> Frontend : http://cultor.com:3000

> Backend : http://api.cultor.com (Kubernetes cluster running on Digital Ocean)

When I login, the backend **IS** responding with the cookie session but the *chrome browser*/*NextJS* is **NOT** setting up/ persisting the cookies in the browser.

This is the response I get after the POST signin request to backend :

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Request-Headers: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 121
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Sat, 28 Nov 2020 11:02:22 GMT
ETag: W/"79-LcIX9p2xnJIZXWCKfe2Zu2KbZgk"
Set-Cookie: express:sess=eyJqd3QiOiJleUpoYkdjaU9pSklVekkxTmlJc0luUj
wWFZDSjadslkjhuZXlKcFpDSTZJalZtWXpJeU9XWmtOalk1T1RWaU1EQXhPV05qTVRC
sc0lqb2lkR1alkjsdfhaEVCMFpYTjBMbU52YlNJc0ltbGhkQ0k2TVRZd05qVTJNVE0r
hRWtpSW5SR1o1RTlZNmZ5askjfdhWUdqMWZFLXRnU3RILUI2UzJPZ1UifQ==; path=/; httponly
```

I would really appreciate the help, I need to take this MERN application live very soon.

Comment: Can you please share the cookies/express-session code from index/app.js file

Comment: It happens due to the reason that the server is not configured about the origin/client for which cookies need to be set

Comment: try using cors to allow so or  add domains/sameSite to the session configure in app.js

Comment: Apparently it is open for for all the origins. What exactly do you want to see?